# How do we track the impact expired entries have on a time series table?

Tags: cassandra

We are processing the oldest data as it comes into the time-series table. I am taking care to make sure that the oldest entries expire as soon as they are processed. Expectation is to have all the deletes at the bottom part of the clustering column of TimeUUID. So query will always read time slot without any deleted entries.

Will this scheme work? Are there any impacts of the expired columns that I should be aware of?

Comment: Is it some sort of batch processing and if so what is the processing interval?  It will help with defining the window for Time Window compaction strategy.

Comment: The query to read the entries are are read every X minutes. After being read the entries are marked with a short TTL, so they expire.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, have added my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So keeping the timeuuid as part of clustering key guarantee the sort order to provide the most recent data.

**If Cassandra 3.1 (DSE 5.x) and above :-**

Now regarding the deletes, "*avoid manual and use TWCS*": Here is how

Let's say every X minutes your job process the data. Lets say X = 5min, (hopefully less than 24hours). Set the compaction to TWCS: Time Window Compaction Strategy and lets assume with TTL of 24hours.

```
WITH compaction= {
'compaction_window_unit': 'HOURS',
'compaction_window_size': '1',                                                                                      
};
```

Now there are 24buckets created in a day, each with one hour of data. These 24 buckets simply relates to 24 sstables (after compaction) in your Cassandra data directory. Now during the 25hour, the entire 1st bucket/sstable would automatically get dropped by TTL. Hence instead of coding for deletes, let Cassandra take care of the cleanup. The beauty of TWCS is to TTL the entire data within that sstable.

Now the READs from your application always goes to the recent bucket, 24th sstable in this case always. So the reads would never have to scan through the tombstones (caused by TTL).

**If Cassandra 2.x or DSE 4.X, if TWCS isn't available yet :-**

A way out till you upgrade to Cassandra 3.1 or above is to use artificial buckets. Say you introduce a time bucket variable as part of the partition key and keep the bucket value to be date and hour. This way each partition is different and you could adjust the bucket size to match the job processing interval.

So when you delete, only the processed partition gets deleted and will not come in the way while reading unprocessed ones. So scanning of tombstones could be avoided.

Its an additional effort on application side to start writing to the correct partition based on the current date/time bucket. But its worth it in production scenario to avoid Tombstone scan.

Comment: which version of cassandra is this available in ? we are using 3.1.0

Comment: I am concerned that I may not be able to use TWCS.  It appears to be recent. However, I am keeping track of a processed state in a column and only retrieving those entries. So even if the timeentry is still sticking around, it should not be retrieved.

Comment: Even with the processed state column, it still has to scan tombstone cells at partition level while its scanning for live rows. A way out till you upgrade to Cassandra 3.1 or above is to use artificial buckets. Say you introduce a time bucket variable as part of the partition key and keep the bucket value to be date and hour. This way each partition is different and you could adjust the bucket size to match the job processing interval. So when you delete, only the processed partition gets deleted and will not come in the way while reading unprocessed ones. So scan tombstones could be avoided.

Comment: @treefrog Have I address all your concerns in the latest answer?

Comment: @treefrog Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to Accept your Answers to the questions you ask

Comment: many thanks for the helpful answer. This is infact what i have done, in order to avoid wide rows, not for avoiding tombstone scanning. However I am querying all the time buckets everytime because I did not want to tie the job intreval to the bucket time. Seemed like different concerns. I want to monitor how many tombstones are scanned. Is there a way ?

Comment: You should be able to track the tombstone ratio via the JMX exposed metric called TombstoneScannedHistogram. It's worth plugging it to any of the monitoring tool like graphite, grafana, datadog, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TWCS to easily manage expired data, and perform filtering by some timestamp column on query time, to ensure that your query always getting the last results.

How do you "taking care" about oldest entries expiry? Cassandra will not show records with expired ttl, but they will persist in sstables until next compaction for this sstable. If you are deleting the rows by yourself, you can't make sure that your query will always read latest records, since Cassandra is eventually consistent, and theoretically there's can be some moments, when you will read stale data (or many such moments, based on your consistency settings).